# CentOS, mod_evasive log write permissions and email issue

Tags: email, logging, centos, apache2, mod-evasive

i'm on CentOS 6.5 now, 
installed mod_evasive some time ago but email notify and logging never worked...

into messages log i have many lines like this...

```
mod_evasive[4548]: Couldn't open logfile /var/log/httpd/evasive/dos-157.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied
```

on CentOS I thought that the owner of the directory /var/log/httpd/evasive should be "apache" and that is with 755..
no way...

then, mailx is already installed and updated... someone says to see into mod_evasive20.c but i can't find this mod_evasive20.c file on my CentOS... where can be? is it possible to send with sendmail instead of mailx? thanks

Answer (score 4):

On CentOS /var/log/httpd has permission 700 and is owned by root, so you need to move /var/log/httpd/evasive to /var/log/evasive and do:

```
chown 0:apache /var/log/evasive
chmod 770 /var/log/evasive
```

If you use SELinux:

```
semanage fcontext --add -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/log/evasive(/.*)?"
restorecon -r /var/log/evasive
```

And add this line to /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_evasive.conf:

```
DOSLogDir /var/log/evasive
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you're facing two problems, first file permission to mod_evasive logdir and second the mail command isn't found.

**1) file permission to "DOSLogDir"**

You must ensure the apache's user has execute and write permissions through the whole directory tree to target "DOSLogDir".
See this example from an ubuntu system

```
root@ubuntu:/var/log# ll
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   adm    4096 Mar 10 14:06 apache2/

root@ubuntu:/var/log# ll apache2
drwxrwxr-x 2 root www-data   4096 Mar 10 14:25 mod_evasive/

root@ubuntu:/var/log# ll apache2/mod_evasive/
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    5 Mar 10 14:25 dos-172.16.245.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    5 Mar 10 14:19 dos-172.16.245.129
```

**2) access mail binary**

The mail binary is defined in mod_evasive20.c indeed, row 45 :

```
    #define MAILER  "/bin/mail %s"
```

Try to get a symlink on mailx to be used by mod_evasive

```
ln -s $(which mailx) /bin/mail
```

Answer (score 1):

understood,

for whom have the same problem hope this helps...

if mod_evasive is not able to write on the dir it doesn't even send the email
so commented out the DOSLogDir and so it writes to tmp...

don't know if can use another directory but for the moment problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue while creating new project into the centos7.

ErrorLog /var/log/httd/mydomain_error.log

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_access.log

**Solution:**

***You need to disable the SELinux and Your issue will be resolved.***

FOr that you need to follow the following steps.

**1) Check the SELinux Status**

> sestatus

OutPut will be like this

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

**2) Disable SELinux**

You can temporarily change the SELinux mode from targeted to permissive with the following command:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

You can see more here : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/